# replace numeric with a given replacement character in a data.frame in R

Tags: r, regex, string, dataframe, vector

I have various types of data.frames each of which can include a long number *somewhere* in them. `A` and `B` are two real examples.

I was wondering how I can replace any numeric element in column `ct` with a given `replacement.name`?

Please see reproducible R code and *desired output* is below.

```
A <- data.frame(ct = c("C,0.839662447257384 - T,0.839662447257384", "No,C,0.44462447257384 - Yes,T,0444462447257384"))

B <- data.frame(ct = "0.822125181950509,C,Female - 0.822125181950509,T,Female")

replacement.name = "year"  # Put this in place of any numeric value in column `ct`


A.desired <- data.frame(ct = c("C,year - T,year", "No,C,year - Yes,T,year"))

B.desired <- data.frame(ct = "year,C,Female - year,T,Female")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `gsub` to remove digits along with `.` and replace with 'year'

```
A$ct <- gsub("[0-9.]+", "year", A$ct)
A$ct
#[1] "C,year - T,year"        "No,C,year - Yes,T,year"

B$ct <- gsub("[0-9.]+", "year", B$ct)
B$ct
#[1] "year,C,Female - year,T,Female"
```

---

The above solution there is a bug i.e. if there are `.` in other places, it could replace it.  To avoid that

```
gsub("[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+", "year", B$ct)
```

---

If these are done on multiple datasets, we can create a function

```
f1 <- function(dat, colnm, replstr){
      dat[[colnm]] <- gsub("[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+", replstr, dat[[colnm]])
      dat
     }

f1(A, 'ct', 'year')
```

Comment: @rnorouzian no, it is not needed.  the `$` was to specify the position at the end of the string.  Since the position is not fixed, it is not needed

Comment: @rnorouzian sorry, forgot that part.  You can just assign. updated